# Reference error for unit test

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, vs-unit-testing-framework

I created a unit test project on my computer #1 and pushed it in the git repository.  Everything works fine on my computer #1.

But when I checked out the project on another computer #2, there are yellow flags in the references (TestFramework, TestAdapter and 2 others).

I updated the packages and it looks successful.  I can find the DLLs in the /package sub-directory, but Visual Studio 2017 doesn't see them.

How can I make it work?  Do I need to put all files in the /package sub-directory into git?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.  I opened the project file with Windows Notepad.  There were 2 lines of definitions for the referenced DLL - one is "package/xxx" and the other one is "../../package/xxx".  After removing "package/xxx", it works fine now.

I think this is a bug of Visual Studio 2017.